# Is there a dictionary, that describe a slight difference between synonyms?

Tags: synonyms, dictionaries

For example, there are three synonyms "concern", "relate to", "be about".

Is there a dictionary, that describe a slight difference between them?

Comment: Through online you can find a one, but in stores i dont know.

Comment: I *wish* such a thing existed, but sadly that is not one of the functions of a thesaurus.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources. @Queue Overflow - I'd have thought *any* good dictionary would come close to what you're looking for, if only because they'll have at least separate sub-definition for each significantly distinct meaning. Some, like OED, will have completely separate main entries if there are multiple etymologies (i.e. - ***fluke** = 1:flatworm, 2:stroke of luck, 3:whale's tail,* etc.).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources. There is a very useful [compilation of resources](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) on the Meta site that includes a number of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merriam-Webster has a Dictionary of Synonyms that might be what you’re looking for.

Their entry for “concern” reads:

> **concern** *vb*
>
> “Concern” [and] “affect” are sometimes confused. “Concern” implies the bearing or influence, [whereas] “affect” [implies] the direct operation or action of one thing on another; this, a piece of legislation may *concern* (that is, have to do with, have reference or relation to) certain vested interests without *affecting* them (that is, producing an effect upon them, changing them in any way).
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of Synonyms, entry for “concern”](http://books.google.com/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&lpg=PA126&vq=concern&pg=PA171#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sub>

The end of that entry has a starred synonym “about”, the entry for which reads:

> **about, concerning, regarding, respecting** are synonymous prepositions when they take an object that names something which is the subject of talk, thought, or interest. **About** is usually interchangeable with any of the others without marked loss of meaning, but it alone may follow its object as will as precede it (“talk *about* many things” or “there is nothing to complain *about*”). **Concerning** is more meaningful because it often retains its verbal implications of affecting and influencing (“make laws *concerning* public welfare”). *Regarding* and *respecting* suggest little more than *about:* however **regarding** is especially appropriate when its object names the goal or center of attention or thought (“they avoided all discussion *regarding* the scandal”). **Respecting** is felicitously employed when selectiveness or specification is to be implied (“he had nothing to say *respecting* Spain”).
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of Synonyms, entry for “about”](http://books.google.com/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&lpg=PA126&vq=concern&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sub>